# TeamCity and Windows Azure Blob Storage

Tags: azure, continuous-integration, teamcity, azure-blob-storage

I have setup a TeamCity server on my machine and the build is running quite well, for your information, I am building a Unity application with Plastic SCM as VCS.

I would like to know if it's possible to send the result of the build to a Windows Azure Blob Storage easily ?

Comment: it looks like TeamCity has a plugin to make an Azure VM, but I'm not sure if that's what you are asking? http://blog.jetbrains.com/teamcity/2014/11/introducing-teamcity-azure-plugin-run-builds-in-the-cloud/  One solution might be to make the VM and then back it up to blob storage from there using PowerShell.

Comment: RIght, I was looking for the PowerShell solution. Thank you !

Comment: Cool, I'll move this to answers if that works for you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution that I can think of, mentioned in comments above: use the TeamCity plugin, then use Powershell to back up the VM to Blob Storage.

This blog by the Scripting Guy explains the PowerShell process http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2014/01/24/create-backups-of-virtual-machines-in-windows-azure-by-using-powershell.aspx but in a nutshell,

Get-AzureOSDisk and Get-AzureDataDisk commands to get your disks, create a container using New-AzureStorageContainer.
Start-AzureStorageBlobCopy backs up VHD to blob storage on your new container.